# problem with indentation of acronyms in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, indentation, acronyms

I'm trying to add manually some acronyms to the beginning of a work. For that I use the `acronym` package. I would like to add that section to the table of content without the dots and the indentation.
Right now the result looks like:
[image]

But I would like to have the "Abkürzungsverzeichnis" in the same style as the "Abbildungen". I tried it, but didn't achieve anything. The code looks more or less like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}
...
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addsec{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[slmtA]
 \acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
 \acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
 \acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\end{acronym}
\newpage
```

Anybody maybe has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoF etc. are chapters by default. So you have to use `\addchap` for your »Abkürzungsverzeichnis«. Then the `\newpage` command in your MWE can be removed.

It seems that you are using option `listof=totoc` to get ToC entries for LoF etc.

```latex
\documentclass[listof=totoc,ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\begin{acronym}[slmtA]
 \acro{KDE}{K Desktop Environment}
 \acro{SQL}{Structured Query Language}
 \acro{Bash}{Bourne-again shell}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional remarks: `a4paper` and `fontsize=11pt` are defaults for `scrreprt`. Package `inputenc` with option `utf8` is only needed, if you use an outdated TeX distribution.

Comment: great, thank you so much!!